# Need to unnest elements in XML file using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm fairly new to xslt, working on my first transform.

Here is a sample of a part of my XML file:

```
<inline-formula id="if1">
    <f>
        <b>AB
            <mit>CD</mit>
        EF</b>=
        <g>d</g>
        <sup>2</sup>
        <inf>1</inf>
    </f>
</inline-formula>
```

Using xslt 2.0, I would like to unnest the `<mit>` element inside the `<b>` element to:

```
<inline-formula id="if1">
    <f>
        <b>AB</b>
        <mit>CD</mit>
        <b>EF</b>=
        <g>d</g>
        <sup>2</sup>
        <inf>1</inf>
    </f>
</inline-formula>
```

There are 15 such elements that could occur in any nested combinations, so ideally the code would allow me to unnest any possible combination.

I've looked through many questions concerning the flattening of XML files but nothing I've tried so far has worked. Any assistance or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are these nested elements always contained in an `f` element?

Comment: dave, they could also be in an `fl` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transform below uses a copy transform, and matches elements within an `f` or `f1` that also further have a nested element.

For matched items, it recursively flattens the elements.

This is more complicated than Tim C's answer.  But, this can work with more levels of nesting.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[self::f | self::f1]/*[*]">
    <xsl:call-template name="flattenElement">
        <xsl:with-param name="pElement" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="flattenElement">
    <xsl:param name="pElement" as="element()" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$pElement/node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::*">
                <xsl:call-template name="flattenElement">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pElement" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{local-name($pElement)}">
                    <xsl:sequence select="normalize-space()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to unnest the `<mit>` element inside the `<b>` element

That's not exactly what your example shows. In order to get the expected result, you must (a) remove the existing `b` wrapper and (b) create a new `b` element for every text node child of `b`:

**XSLT 1.0/2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b/text()">
    <b>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </b>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> There are 15 such elements that could occur in any nested
>   combinations, so ideally the code would allow me to unnest any
>   possible combination.

Not sure what that means.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. The last sentence of my original question means that in addition to `b` and `mit`, there are 13 other elements (`bg`, `bi`, `blkbd`, `bsc`, `g`, `ge`, `it`, `rf`, `rm`, `sc`, `scp`, `ssf`, and `ty`) that could be nested in any combination like the `b` and `mit` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick for you....?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="inline-formula/*/*[* and text()]">
     <xsl:apply-templates  />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="inline-formula/*/*[*]/text()">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(parent::*)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This looks "grandchildren" of the `inline-formula` element, that happen to have a mix of text and element children, and for the text elements, it wraps them in a copy of their parent tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.